# Let $f\in\mathbb{R}(x)$ be a rational function and $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}, \forall x\in\mathbb{Z}$, prove that $f$ is a polynomial.

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, integers, rational-functions

Let $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$, $g,h\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ be two polynomials and $(g,h)=1$. It's easy to show that $deg(g)> deg(h)$ by taking $x\to \infty$. But since $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}(x)$, for $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, $g(a),h(a)$ may not in $\mathbb{Z}$. Hence it's not easy to say whether $f(a)\in\mathbb{Z}$ when $deg(h)\ge 1$. I don't know how to use the tool of algebra.

Any ideas?

Comment: The first trick is to show that $f$ can be written as $f = q(x) + \frac {r(x)}{d(x)}$ where $q,r,d$ are polynomials with integer coefficients and degree of $d$ is more than degree of $r$ (this is true of *all* rational expressions. Not just those that generate integers). As degree of $d > $ degree of $r$ there is an $N$ so that $x > N\implies |d(x)| > |r(x)|$.